# Executing an overriden method, triggers the un-overridden one

Tags: dart

With the change to `StreamEventTransformer`, I have to create a wrapper class that behave like  `StreamEventTransformer`, so here's the code:

```dart
class Transformer implements EventSink, StreamTransformer {
  EventSink rootSink;

  Transformer();
  Transformer._useSink(this.rootSink);

  void handleData(event, EventSink sink) {
    print('inside handleData');
    sink.add(event);
  }

  void handleError(error, StackTrace stackTrace, EventSink sink) =>
      sink.addError(error, stackTrace);

  void add(event) {
    print('inside add');
    handleData(event, rootSink);
  }


  void addError(error, [StackTrace stackTrace]) =>
      handleError(error, stackTrace, rootSink);

  void close() => rootSink.close();

  Stream bind(Stream source) =>
      new Stream.eventTransformed(source, (EventSink sink) {
        EventSink eventSink = new Transformer._useSink(sink);
        return eventSink;
      });
}
```

with this class, I just have to extends from `Transformer` to adapt with the change.

But when I extends it:

```dart
class PlusOneTransformer extends Transformer {
  void handleData(data, sink) {
    sink.add(data + 1);
  }
}
```

and test it:

```dart
void main() {
  StreamController controller = new StreamController();
  Stream stream = controller.stream.transform(new PlusOneTransformer());
  stream.listen(print);
  controller.add(10);
}
```

I'm expecting the output is:

```
inside add
11
```

but instead:

```
inside add
inside handleData
10
```

So it's not running the overridden `handleData`, it's running the old one. From debugger I can see the executed class is `Transformer` not `PlusOneTransformer` while I'm using `PlusOneTransformer` to transform the stream.

Am I missing something?

Comment: post your code for StreamController

Comment: not sure about that, if you mean how I instantiate it, it's on the main function

Comment: Isn't stream controller an abstract class though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error lies in this line:

```dart
 new Transformer._useSink(sink);
```

This will allocate a `Transformer` and not the subclass.

The easiest solution: don't allocate a fresh sink, but reuse the one you already have:

```dart
  Stream bind(Stream source) =>
      new Stream.eventTransformed(source, (EventSink sink) {
        this.rootSink = sink;
        return this;
      });
```

Since the transformer is not reusable it is probably be a good idea to check this:

```dart
  Stream bind(Stream source) =>
      new Stream.eventTransformed(source, (EventSink sink) {
        if (this.rootSink != null) {
          throw new StateError("Transformer already used");
        }
        this.rootSink = sink;
        return this;
      });
```